# Clean up dangling Docker Containers in githost hosted gitlab-ci runners?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

it seems like there is a well documented issue with dangling Docker containers piling up in a githost.io-hosted gitlab-ci runner.
All of the solutions I found require full shell access, which doesn't seem to be possible using the SaaS solution on githost.
When I try to use the docker cli as a script in a .gitlab-ci.yml, it won't work. Unless of course I use a specific docker image with Docker, and then I would have a Docker in Docker.
Can I actually clean up the hanging containers in the host system with a docker in docker?!
Has anyone run into this and found a solution to mitigate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue as well a couple of months ago and got into contact with their support desk. At that time, customers couldn't remove old, dangling docker images (i.e. docker images without a tag). They said they would create an issue to improve this, but I haven't heard back that it is already implemented.
So until that time the only option is to call their support desk and have them do it for you.